# Linking to another html file works on localhost, but not when I upload it on server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, twitter

My folder structure looks like this: **updated**

```
/public
  twitter.html
  /styles
    styles.css
/views
  index.html
server.js
package.json
```

I have a index.html that is linked to twitter.html. I use Express and Node.js in the .js file so I am linking like this:

```
<a href="/twitter">Twitter</a>
```

I cannot use `<a href="twitter.html">Twitter</a>` because it doesn't work with Express, it will only give me this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmNQG.jpg (on web browser) when it's supposed to be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZdnP.jpg (on localhost)

When I run localhost, everything works as intended, I click on the link to twitter and it works. I go from `http://localhost:3000/` to `http://localhost:3000/twitter`.

However, when I open index.html on my web browser and then click on the link to twitter it says "Your file was not found". I go from `file:///Users/name/twitter/views/index.html` to `file:///twitter`.

When I upload these files to a web server and I click on the twitter link it says 'Not Found The requested URL /twitter was not found on this server.'. I go from `http://mypage.com/myusername/views/index.html` to `http://mypage.com/twitter`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong as everything works when running on localhost?

My script.js looks like this: **updated**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
let db

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://someuser:somepassword@cluster0-shard-00-00-fquoc.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-fquoc.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-fquoc.mongodb.net:27017/twitter?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin', (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
})

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
app.set('view engine', 'html')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.get('/public/twitter', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('tweets').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    res.send('/public/twitter.html')
  })
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.render('index');
   });

app.post('/tweets', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('tweets').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)

    console.log('saved to database')
    res.redirect('/twitter')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If your twitter page is inside the /views folder then access it accordingly.
 `<a href="/views/twitter.html> Twitter </a>`

**update**: now that you posted your routing code which is your issue. `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Get rid of your views and stick the twitter page in a public directory, then do /public/twitter and you will be fine

```
app.get('/public/twitter', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('tweets').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/public/" + "twitter.html" );
  })
})
```

Comment: .html extension does not work with Express. That's what I did at the beginning, but after using Express/Node.js I had to make routers for it to work. Doing what you said gives me access to the website but it will look like this: imgur.com/a/DL9aM and on localhost it says: Cannot GET /twitter.html I've updated my post to show how my .js file looks like with routing.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I removed `app.use(expr..` code line and wrote `<a href="/twitter.html> Twitter </a>` in index.html and it worked on local host. I also tried again on my web browser to click on twitter.html through index.html and it still says cannot get file.. Am I misunderstanding anything? Still don't understand why it wouldn't work on a browser.

Comment: Edited my answer. It works with CSS when I removed `app.use(expr..`, but not when opening index.html in web browser and then clicking on twitter.html link.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the .js file and folder structure in the original post. In index.html I am linking like this `<a href="/public/twitter">Twitter</a>`. On the browser, I now arrive at a blank page that only says 'twitter.html' and on localhost "Your file was not found". Did I forget to add or remove anything?  - Is php not different than Express? I used jQuery in my .js file but had to change to node and Express to make it work with databases, but thanks, maybe I should put this project on the shelf! Not good with server side languages at all. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Yeah I am an idiot, you are just sending the string, sorry its been long day, You want to send the file. res.sendFile( __dirname + "/public/" + "twitter.html" ); Try out a few combinations, you can try with and without __dirname